# How should I go about saving lots of data when the data will not be static. iOS, Cocoa Touch, Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, database, cocoa-touch

Alright, I really am not sure how to go about saving a bunch of data on my iOS app. The app will allow a user to create an Entry, that entry will have a timestamp for it's name. For each entry, I need to store multiple kinds of data (NSString, Boolean, Double, Float).

Each Entry will have to save information kind of like the following:

/////////

Float

Float

Float

Float

Float

NSString

NSString

NSString

NSString

NSString

Boolean

Boolean

Boolean

//////////

So, a total of thirteen values per Entry. However, the amount of entries can be created indefinitely and will keep changing. Therefore, how should I go about storing all this information. I am very new at this, so far all I have used is `NSUserDefaults`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lots of entry objects, Core Data looks to be a good fit for this.  It's also a great framework to have in your toolbelt when working with data intensive applications.  You basically map out your data model, then you export your model into custom objects that can be queried against (much like a database).

Lynda.com has a great teaching series on it but you can find a great reference from Apple over here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since they are quite dynamic in order or type, you could just use a collection class (e.g. `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`) which holds objc object representations of your data. These types adopt `NSCoding` -- so long as their elements/contents are also `NSCoding` compatible (e.g. `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSNumber` or `CFBoolean` (for boolean)), you're good to go.

`NSKeyedArchiver` is a good option when your fields/types are invariant.

Answer (score 0):

Use CoreData. It is very flexible offers excellent solutions for migrating data from one schema to another and is tightly integrated with iCloud. Start here:

[CoreData Getting Started](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GettingStartedWithCoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005316)